Maximizer SQL data export
I'm trying to export a specific column within the database to a file. The column contains BLOB data, saved by the Maximizer Outlook addon.
From what I have researched it seems that the column, a VARCHAR(MAX), has it's data encoded as "OLE".
Now I can pretty confidently export everything else in the DB, as well as some types in that column (PDF, DOC), but cannot get it to export the saved email content.
I have tried just a normal BLOB write to the presumed extention, such as .msg. This works for the PDF en DOC files, but not the email content. Reading the BLOB data and putting it into a HTML file makes it somewhat readable, as the mail content contains HTML, but I am then unable to see the attachments.
I have tried parsing the data to the php_mailparse. No luck.
I have also exported and built the files directly from SQL Server with some SQL QUERIES, but only been able to do the PDF and DOC properly.
I have also build an extraction method in C# to lo luck.
Specifically the email content thats saved in the BLOB does not want to export in a usable manner.
Anyone have any ideas?
Here is the SQL I have used.

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;


EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
DECLARE @outPutPath varchar(50) = 'C:\export'
, @i bigint
, @init int
, @data varbinary(max) 
, @fPath varchar(max)  
, @folderPath  varchar(max) 
 

DECLARE @Doctable TABLE (id int identity(1,1), [Data_Machine_Id]  varchar(100) , [Sequence_Number]  varchar(100), [TextCol] varBinary(max) )
 
INSERT INTO @Doctable([Data_Machine_Id] ,[TextCol])
Select [Data_Machine_Id],[TextCol] FROM  [dbo].[AMGR_Letters_Tbl]
  WHERE [Client_Id] = '160505111841583611250C' AND [Sequence_Number] = '329002';
 
--SELECT * FROM @table

SELECT @i = COUNT(1) FROM @Doctable
 
WHILE @i >= 1
BEGIN 

    SELECT 
     @data = [TextCol],
     @fPath = @outPutPath + '\' + '\' + 'test.msg',
     @folderPath = @outPutPath + '\'
    FROM @Doctable WHERE id = @i
 
  --Create folder first
  
  EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT; -- An instace created
  EXEC sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1;  
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open'; -- Calling a method
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @data; -- Calling a method
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @fPath, 2; -- Calling a method
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close'; -- Calling a method
  EXEC sp_OADestroy @init; -- Closed the resources
 
  print 'Document Generated at - '+  @fPath   

--Reset the variables for next use
SELECT @data = NULL  
, @init = NULL
, @fPath = NULL  
, @folderPath = NULL
SET @i -= 1
END


Screenshot of the HEX data.
SSV data screenshot

I don't quite follow, is your problem exporting blob or parsing blob into something readable? SO is usually for one question per customer

So what is the question? If you save the data as a file with the .MSG extension, can Outlook successfully open it? If yes, are you looking for a way to extract the data from an MSG file?

@DmitryStreblechenko - I just wish to save it as a .MSG file and be able to open it later with outlook. Outlook can open it, but the information inside is not correct. No To, From, Subjects or attachments. The body has content, but seems encoded and does not justify the file size. A few lines of encoded text for a 8mb file.

@siggemannen - I can export the blob data ok, for when I export pdf or word doc blob data, i can create the file and it opens up correctly.
Only when I export the email message to .MSG (or any other email format, .EML included) it does not produce a file with the correct content.

@KJ - I believe the format to be .MSG, as that is a microsoft format and the readable information I can get from the blob indicates that it is a microsoft OLE document. The program, Maximizer, can open the email from from blob content and produce a valid file, with all email info and attachments. But it does not have the option to export that from the front end.

Most likely that means the format is not MSG file. Try to open the file in a binary editor and post a screenshot of the few first few dozen bytes showing the data in hex.

@DmitryStreblechenko - Screenshot added as requested. This is of the data after export.
In the DB, the BLOB data starts with "0xD0CF11E0A1B11AE100000000000000000000000000000000"

It does look like an OLE storage file (much like MSG and the old DOC/XLS/etc. formats), but it is not MSG. Try to see if you can figure out where and how the actual data is stored using a structured storage viewer such as one from https://www.mitec.cz/ssv.html

@DmitryStreblechenko - Wow, thank you for the link. Gives me a lot of info.
I have uploaded a new screenshot of what is in the blob data when exported.
I can expand on those folders and see meaningful data.
Now the question remains how do I extract that data then?

That looks like their own custom format. You can of course parse it now that you know the names of the streams/storages, but that would require at least C# or any other compiled language that can use the OLE storage API.

@DmitryStreblechenko - Thank you. I'm on the right track now.

I found that saving the 'Email Message' documents works if you save them as ".eml" instead of ".msg"

Have you tested it with a Maximizer database? Because from What I found the blob content was a custom OLE object. I have made a python script to extract that info and rebuild it to an .eml file.

I have resolved this by creating a python script to extract the blob data, organize it, and then create a new .eml file from that.
This newly created .eml file can be opened in any mail application and all mail addresses and attachments are present.
Thank you @DmitryStreblechenko for putting me on the right path.
